# Html5 Border-Radius Reverse Fill

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve drop-down button as per following design image. See drop-down menu starts just after middle of button. My problem is that button has transparent background to utilize background image from root parent div.

[image]

So far I have achieved following image. As I said above, I want to achieve white edges outside of border-radius.

[image]

```css
    .dropdown-header {
      border-top-left-radius: 20px;
      border-top-right-radius: 20px;
      width: 210px;
      height: 185px;
      margin: auto;
    }
    
    
    .div-user-header {
      width: 210px;
      margin: auto;
      position: relative;
    
      border-top-left-radius: 20px;
      border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    
    }
    
    .div-user-header-1 {
      width: 206px;
      height: 24px;
      border: 2px solid #9CB2C7;
      border-radius: 20px;
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 5px;
    
    }
    
    .div-user-header-1 a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #FCCC00;
      display: block;
    
    }
    
    
    .div-user-header-list {
      position: absolute;
      background-color: white;
      height: 170px;
      width: 210px;
    
    
    }
    
    .div-user-header-2 a {
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #8C8C8C;
    }
    
    .div-user-header-2 {
      height: 40px;
      padding: 12px 15px;
    
    
    }
    
    .div-user-header-3 a {
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #8C8C8C;
    }
    
    .div-user-header-3 {
      height: 40px;
      padding: 12px 15px;
    
    }
    
    .div-add-profile-card {
    
      padding: 0px 15px;
    }
    
    .div-add-profile-card a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #8C8C8C;
      font-size: 10px;
      padding: 12px;
      display: block;
      border-top: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="dropdown-header">
        <div class="div-user-header">
          <div class="div-user-header-1">
            <a href="#profileuser01">ProfileUser 01</a>
          </div>
          <div class="div-user-header-list">
            <div class="div-user-header-2">
              <img src="../../../assets/images/avtar2.png" width="34px" height="34px" style="padding-right: 5px; vertical-align: middle" />
              <a href="#profileuser02">ProfileUser 01</a>
            </div>
            <div class="div-user-header-3">
              <img src="../../../assets/images/user-02.png" width="30px" height="30px" style="padding-right:5px; vertical-align: middle" />
              <a href="#profileuser03">ProfileUser 02</a>
            </div>
            <div class="div-add-profile-card">
              <a href="add profile card"> + Add Profile Cards</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Any suggestion would be really helpful.

Comment: show your code please image doesnot help

Comment: I just added relevant html and css files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Use `::after` `::before` pseudo elements for the dropdown and apply separate `background-image` as marked in the image. Apply `position:absolute` and align then in the top left and right corners based on the design.

Comment: Yes, it seems only image based approach. What about clip-path based approach ?

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. You have achieved almost 99%. Just add below styles to your CSS of `.div-user-header-list` as below:

```
.div-user-header-list {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    height: 170px;
    width: 210px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

See the updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/8ukj3wy1/1/

Comment: It's not correct way as per my requirement. As I mentioned in question I want to stick drop-down button background=transparent. Your fiddle skips that requirement. See my new fiddle in your approach with my requirement. https://jsfiddle.net/8ukj3wy1/2/

Comment: It is again so simple. Create an illusion for the user. Apply the same backgorud image to the drop-down button which is used on document body. 

Answer (score 0):

Check this one out:
[image]
https://jsfiddle.net/sLy7fnzg/

Essentially use a negative margin to move the `.div-user-header-list` up and use relative positioning to enable z-indexes.

Also, to resolve the issue with the half border, remove the border from the `.div-user-header-1` and add a whole element as a `::before` to the `.div-user-header` like so:

```
.div-user-header::before {
    content: "";
    background: #9CB2C7;
    width: 210px;
    height: 30px;
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
    body{
        background-color: grey;
    }
        .dropdown-header {
      border-top-left-radius: 20px;
      border-top-right-radius: 20px;
      width: 210px;
      height: 203px;
      margin: auto;
      overflow: hidden;
      /*background-color: #fff;*/
    }

    .div-user-header-list:before,
    .div-user-header-list:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;

        height: 10px;
        width: 20px;

        bottom: 0;
    }
        .div-user-header-list:before {
        /*right: -20px;*/
        left: 1px;
        top: -10px;
        border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;

        -webkit-box-shadow: -10px 0 0 0 #fff;
        box-shadow: -10px 0 0 0 #fff;
    }

    .div-user-header-list:after {
        /*left: -20px;*/
        right: 1px;
        top: -10px;
        border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;

        -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 0 0 0 #fff;
        box-shadow: 10px 0 0 0 #fff;
    }
    .div-user-header {
      width: 210px;
      margin: auto;
      position: relative;

      border-radius: 20px;      

    }

    .div-user-header-1 {
      width: 206px;
      height: 24px;
      border: 2px solid #9CB2C7;
      border-radius: 20px;
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 5px;

    }

    .div-user-header-1 a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #FCCC00;
      display: block;

    }


    .div-user-header-list {
      position: absolute;
      background-color: white;
      height: 170px;
      width: 210px;
        /*margin-top: -14px;
    z-index: -9;
    padding-top: 14px;*/

    }

    .div-user-header-2 a {
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #8C8C8C;
    }

    .div-user-header-2 {
      height: 40px;
      padding: 12px 15px;


    }

    .div-user-header-3 a {
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #8C8C8C;
    }

    .div-user-header-3 {
      height: 40px;
      padding: 12px 15px;

    }

    .div-add-profile-card {

      padding: 0px 15px;
    }

    .div-add-profile-card a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #8C8C8C;
      font-size: 10px;
      padding: 12px;
      display: block;
      border-top: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
    }   


    </style>

</head>    

<body>

<div class="dropdown-header">
        <div class="div-user-header">
          <div class="div-user-header-1">
            <a href="#profileuser01">ProfileUser 01</a>
          </div>
          <div class="div-user-header-list">
            <div class="div-user-header-2">
              <img src="../../../assets/images/avtar2.png" width="34px" height="34px" style="padding-right: 5px; vertical-align: middle" />
              <a href="#profileuser02">ProfileUser 01</a>
            </div>
            <div class="div-user-header-3">
              <img src="../../../assets/images/user-02.png" width="30px" height="30px" style="padding-right:5px; vertical-align: middle" />
              <a href="#profileuser03">ProfileUser 02</a>
            </div>
            <div class="div-add-profile-card">
              <a href="add profile card"> + Add Profile Cards</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```